# Running a docker container to execute python script with minimal footprint

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I have a node.js server that gets an python script as an input from the web client (Yes, risky), the server runs the script and return the output to the client.

In order to minimize the risks here, I'm creating a docker container for the execution of the script with the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name python-script-instance -v /dir/on/server:/tmp python:2 python /tmp/script.py
```

It requires creating a directory on the server that will hold a file named `script.py`, the host server directory is mounted to `/tmp` on the container and allow access to `script.py` through `/tmp/script.py`

I dont wan't to have script.py created on the server, I want to dynamically take it from memory directly into the docker container.

I thought about passing the entire script as a command line argument to the python interpreter, but was unsuccessful to get it to work.

Any suggestions on how can I execute a python script encapsulated in a docker container leaving a minimal footprint on the host server?

Comment: Build the script into the container with the `Dockerfile` don't mount it a mount is a risk.

Comment: Building a custom image, takes a lot more time than docker run, is that normal? take in mind a webserver has to perform the process while the user waits for response.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the script inline using the `-c` option of the Python interpreter:

```
docker run --rm python:2 python -c 'print "Hello Python"'
```